# Restful design: Listing entities vs fetching one

Tags: api, rest

Below is a common pattern in RESTful design:

```
GET /entities/{entity_id} # fetch single entity
GET /entities/ # list all the entities
```

however if users have a bug where entity ID is accidentally set to "" (not uncommon), then that will result in a 200 status (instead of a 400).

Wouldn't `GET /entities/list` be more user friendly? or `GET /entity/{entity_id} + /entities`

Comment: For your last question, would you want to have `GET /entities` and also have `GET /entities/list`?

Comment: What about demanding trailing slashes? `GET /entities/{entity_id}/` so passing in "" results in erroring `GET /entities//`. Even if clients forgets to append a trailing slash it's easy to fix by returning 308.